# Reset counter during output with row_number

Tags: sql, db2, counter, row-number

I have the following SQL Query part:

```
SELECT car, 
       grouper, 
       yearout, 
       rn 

FROM (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY grouper ORDER BY yearout) AS rn, 
             car, 
             grouper, 
             yearout 
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT res.sn AS car, 
                            res.groupin AS groupin,
                            Year(res.yearin) AS yearin
            FROM (inner stuff)) res
      WHERE Year(res.yearin) BETWEEN '2015' AND '2030'
      ORDER BY res.groupin) temp) ALL 

WHERE ALL.rn <= (SELECT taken
                 FROM (SELECT p1.nos - p2.gone AS taken,
                              yearout,
                              group_key
                       FROM (SELECT count(sn) AS nos,
                                    group_key
                             FROM d_fm_cars
                             GROUP BY group_key) p1
                       JOIN (SELECT taken AS gone,
                                    group_key_all,
                                    yearout
                             FROM settings_keys) p2
                         ON p1.group_key = p2.group_key_all) counterin
                 WHERE counterin.yearout = ALL.yearout 
                   AND counterin.group_key_all = ALL.grouper)
```

The values for taken are like

```
5 
15
```

for grouper 1 for the years 2015 and 2016 the problem now is that the result i get from the query just runs 1-15 and not like it should from 1-5 and than again from 1-15 
The available cars per year are

```
2015 3
2016 10
2017 25
```

so the output must run over the years limit and put 2 cars from 2015 into the 2015 output.
When partitioning with grouper and yearout that is not the case anymore. But leaving yearout out it just runs through and does not reset the counter at 5.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think we need to see some starting data.  What should the final results look like (from that starting data)?  What is `"inner stuff"`?  There's a couple of syntax errors in your statement (`p1.nos` and `p2.gone` don't exist, etc).  There are a number of inefficiencies (calling `YEAR(....)` will prevent the optimizer from using indices).  Any time you get 2 nested levels (especially repeatedly), you need to be careful you aren't fighting the system.  Why do you have dates in the future?  Part of solving your problem will be moving some/all of the `WHERE` to an additional `JOIN` (or CTE).

Comment: It sounds to me like you expect this query to do some magic that it won't ever do.  At the heart you doing a query and selecting a sub-set of the results with a value less than another value.   It won't run the query twice and select less than two different values.  You need different syntax for that (UNION ALL between two select statements.)